# DRUID : Get Number of days for a given date range to get average

Tags: druid

Need to have the total number of days for a given interval. I have already tried using distinct of dates for the purpose. It fails because for some days data is not present. Once I have the number of days for the given date interval I will be able to find the daily average.
Any other approaches is also welcomed

Comment: how is it related to druid?

Comment: not able to figure out the query